# Log Reader Agent is not starting

Tags: sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

I have setup transactional replication on SQL SERVER 2014. It was working fine yesterday. Today, I am seeing below error. How to investigate what is the problem. Why log reader agent is not starting up.
[image]

Comment: Can you send the full error log

Comment: Have you checked out the [MS Tutorial for Troubleshooting Transactional Replication #LogReaderAgent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/troubleshoot-tran-repl-errors?view=sql-server-ver15#find-errors-with-the-log-reader-agent)?